# Why can I pass a null paramater to a fun which require a non-null in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The fun `findLast` will return `MDetail?` , so the value of `var aa` maybe be null.

The fun `remove` accept a non-null parameter, but why can the code `listofMDetail.remove(aa)` be compiled ?  Thanks!

And more, the Code A can run normally!

**Code A**

```
private val listofMDetail:MutableList<MDetail> = myGson.fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson)

fun deleteDetailByID(_id:Long){
    var aa=listofMDetail.findLast { it._id == _id };

    //listofMDetail.remove(null)  //It doesn't work     
    listofMDetail.remove(aa)      // It can be compiled

    var bb: MDetail?=null
    listofMDetail.remove(bb)      // It can be compiled

}
```

**Source Code**

```
public interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E> {
    // Modification Operations
    override fun add(element: E): Boolean

    override fun remove(element: E): Boolean

   ...........
}
```

Comment: It's either doing an implicit cast because it assumes you know what you're doing, or it's not being checked at compile time.

Comment: Thanks!  but `var bb: MDetail?=null    listofMDetail.remove(bb)` can run at run time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `aa` and `bb` both are of type `MDetail?`, but the `null` value itself contains no info about type, so the compiler cannot infer the type for you and it's a compile error, but if you cast the `null` to `MDetail?`, then it will be compiled as well:

```
listofMDetail.remove(null as MDetail?)
```

Then the problem is, why the `remove` works when your `listofMDetail` is declared as `MutableList<MDetail>` with no `?` after `MDetail`.

That's because the `remove` method is not resolved to `public interface MutableList<E>`, but `MutableCollections.kt`'s `remove`, here is the code:

```
package kotlin.collections

/**
 * Removes a single instance of the specified element from this
 * collection, if it is present.
 *
 * Allows to overcome type-safety restriction of `remove` that requires to pass an element of type `E`.
 *
 * @return `true` if the element has been successfully removed; `false` if it was not present in the collection.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <@kotlin.internal.OnlyInputTypes T> MutableCollection<out T>.remove(element: T): Boolean
        = @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (this as MutableCollection<T>).remove(element)
```

In your case, the generic type T is `MDetail?`, and `MDetail` is `out T`, so the `remove` will receive a parameter of type `MDetail?`, which permits `null` value.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that the fun `remove(element: T)` require non-null on the surface , but  `remove(element: T)` accept null parameter  in fact ?

Comment: If so, why doesn't kotlin define `remove(element: T)` as `remove(element: T?)`

Comment: No, they are two different functions, just works like overload functions. I don't know the reason, and I think it confused me a little too :)